# Why self-hosted fonts or other files like fav.icon must be located in the /static folder?

Tags: fonts, favicon, custom-font

Why self-hosted fonts  and also other files like the the fav.icon must be located in the /static folder, while other assets like images, are placed inside the /src folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary that the self-hosted fonts and the favicon must be located in the /static folder.
It will work even when it is located in another folder, if the ,mentioned, file directory is correct.
But modern browsers sends request for `/favicon.ico` for the webpages which do not include any favicon mentioned in the html. As: If webpage `example.com/page` does not have a favicon (directory/location) mentioned in its html, then the browser automatically sends request for `example.com/favicon.ico` for the favicon. For that case the `favicon.ico` file should be uploaded at the root directory.