# Why is the favicon only shown in the root page?

Tags: reactjs, favicon, vite

I have a react app and a favicon icon in the folder src. It is only shown for the root path, the other pages cannot find it. In the developer tools, it show a wrong path for a subpage, it tries to get the favicon from http://localhost:3000/faq/src/favicon.ico

index.html

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="src/favicon.ico">
```

it works for http://localhost:3000/ but not for

```
http://localhost:3000/faq
```

Comment: try `href="favicon.ico"` and put the favicon file in the `public` folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting your `favicon` under your public directory would be best.

```
|
 `--- public
     |
      `--- favicon.ico
```

And then refer to it in your `index.html` file like this:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

In React, you can also do the following:

```html
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Can you tell why favicon should be put inside the public directory. As it is not loading when put in the src folder.

Comment: @Neeraj-Kumar-Coder It should be placed in the public directory (root directory), but there is no obligation to prevent you from putting it elsewhere. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67232800/11908502) approximately describes the reason.